# How can I check list in dynamically?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am trying to create custom command which will check **li** contains multiple values, but each time I call the command, I don't know how many values. In other words dynamic number of values.

To check single value, its quite easy, I just do the below:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('getList', (value) => { 
   cy.get('list').contains(value).should('be.visible').click();  
});
```

But I dont understand how I can pass in dynamic values and then check those? any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check for multiple values in a `li`, you can modify your above code to accept an array of values and check then whether they are available in the `li`

```js
let values = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3'] // array of expected list

Cypress.Commands.add('getList', (values) => {
    values.forEach(value =>
        cy.contains('li', value).click()
    )
});
```

Comment: what if I dont know the number of values I want to pass in, e.g. maybe its 5 one time and 10 another time, how do change it to that?

Comment: If you are using array, you don’t need to worry about number of values. Only thing that we require is array of values, it can be of any size.